# How to change CJK fallback font?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, language-support

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from 14.04 LTS. All worked pretty fine except for an issue on Chinese fonts which I've been unable to resolve.

While the font is mostly OK in system applications, it doesn't work well in Chrome: It seems that Chrome automatically uses `Noto Sans` font as the fallback font, which for some reason is only installed in its "thin" variant in 16.04 LTS and thus looks very ugly. In Firefox and many other applications, the font `Wenquanyi Zenhei` is correctly used as the fallback font and it looks much better. If I delete `Noto Sans` from the system, Chrome just gives me blank squares instead of trying to use `Wenquanyi Zenhei`.

I'm not sure why that's happening. Is this something specific to Chrome, that Google intends it to use its own `Noto Sans` font for fallback? Or is it something about system configuration? Or is there some setting in Chrome that I can change? How can I change the fallback font for CJK?(systemwide or just for Chrome)

Answer (score 3):

There was a bug in the fontconfig package (I [reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fonts-noto-cjk/+bug/1575555) the bug, which has since been fixed in fonts-noto-cjk - 1:1.004+repack2-1~ubuntu1) which somehow let Chrome believe that "thin" is the correct weight to use. I removed the package and downloaded NotoSansCJK directly [from Google](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-hans), which contains fonts of different weights in *separate files*. After installing the fonts manually this issue seems to be fixed, and Chrome is able to render CJK correctly even though my default font is still unchanged (Liberation Sans).

Answer (score 1):

The “Noto Sans CJK" font is over 100MB, it is a complete fonts with all weights and all characters in CJK.

Any way, there is something wrong there. My work-around is:
In chromium settings -> customize fonts, change "standard font" to use "Noto Sans CJK", like me use "Noto Sans CJK SC"; I think maybe for Chrome, it is the same.

You can refer to [this qustion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760743/after-15-10-to-16-04-update-some-characters-became-unreadable/763540) or [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1468027) to see more info.

Comment: Yeah, that bug report addresses the problem in comment #113, but doesn't really provide a solution. Does setting the standard font in Chromium result in proper rendering of all the font weights, with "Regular" as default?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson at least, in my Chromium, "Regular" and "Bold" are showing fine and "Regular" is default. I have "en_US.UTF-8" as $LANG in env. But I don't know how to test other weights.

Comment: Did that impact your English font rendering though? I still want to use Liberation Sans as my default sans font for Latin scripts. It seems that the default Latin font in Noto is different from Liberation Sans/Arial/Helvetica series

Comment: @XiangJi, In my Chromium, for askunbunt, changing "standard font" does not affect English font to render. From Chromium inspect tool, it shows English words are shown as "Ubuntu".

Comment: @alfred Sure, that's because AskUbuntu has a font "Ubuntu" defined, so it won't be affected by user setting here. But there could be a difference on websites that does not define what font to use and automatically falls onto the default font, for example Wikipedia.

Comment: @XiangJi Chromium also has setting for sans-serif font, I set as "Arial", so Wikipedia shows "Arial", if I set to "Liberation Sans", it shows "Liberation Sans", I think it should be fine for you, if you also override font by this. unless you have some other way to override Chrome font settings?

Comment: It seems that I was able to solve the issue by removing the package and just manually installing the font from Google (the different weights are contained in separate files in this way), with the default font unchanged.